# Incompatible pointer types assigning to CLLocationManager

Tags: cllocationmanager

So I've developed a standalone compass app (arrow revolving to point tofixed lat/long point) which works perfectly as a standalone project but when I've come to incorporate it into the wider project I get a problem.

Initially I get a semantic warning (Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'CLLocationManager*' from 'CLLoccation *__strong') for:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy >= 0) {

    self.recentLocation = newLocation; (WARNING HERE)

CLLocation *POI2location = [[CLLocation alloc]
                                initWithLatitude:kPOI2Latitude 
                                longitude:kPOI2Longitude];
    CLLocationDistance delta = [POI2location 

                                distanceFromLocation:newLocation];
```

And further on I get a fatal error (Property 'coordinate' not found on object of type 'CLLocationManager) for:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {

if (self.recentLocation != nil && newHeading.headingAccuracy >= 0) {
    CLLocation *POI2Location = [[CLLocation alloc]
                                initWithLatitude:kPOI2Latitude
                                longitude:kPOI2Longitude];

    double course = [self headingToLocation:POI2Location.coordinate
                                    current:recentLocation.coordinate]; (WARNING HERE)
```

For some reason it doesn't like 'recentLocation' now whereas it was all working perfectly before. Can someone point out to me what I'm missing. I'm sure it's obvious to someone with more experience than me.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Started again this morning and the answer is staring me in the face!

In the .h file i'd put

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *recentLocation;
```

when I should have put

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *recentLocation;
```